# trinidad logs not showing this request

Tags: logging, jruby, trinidad-gem

Most of time, trinidad make good logs like this:

```
Started GET "/assets/auth-icons.png" for 10.200.1.228 at 2012-02-16 05:01:20 UTC
```

However, on one particular route/action, it shows only this failure:

```
2012-02-16 05:06:30 SEVERE: Application Error
```

The same request works fine on webrick development macheine.

Thanks

Comment: no more details about the application error shown ?
does this happen in development and production as well ?